# I want to call map.checkResize() but I do NOT know where in my code to call it

Tags: google-maps

I want to call map.checkResize();  // but I do NOT know where in my code(v2) to call it and is it on Map obj?

**symptom:** map appear only to 20-35% of the div horizontally of the div that shows Terms of Use of google in div right bottom corner.

http://www.polisphotos.com/jQueryPb/HFjQ-ch11-end/sightings-w-map.html  // checkout // no server side code here

Answer (score 0):

Your map is shown by clicking the link, which runs this code:

```
javascript:changeDisplay('givemap')
```

which does this:

```
if (element.style.display == 'none')
{
element.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Add the line into that code block, so that *after* making the element display (thus changing its size) you trigger the event to get the API to use the new size.

Comment: map.checkResize(); this just add?